# Breaking up dictionary string into multiple variables in R

Tags: r

I was given a data set where the values in a particular variables look like...

```
{"varname": "value", "varname2": "value2", "varname3": "value3"}
```

and I want a quick efficient way to break this up into 3 separate variables where the var name is the column name and the values are its corresponding vector. It has to be in R otherwise pythons dictionary functionality would tackle this easily. Any Ideas would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you find the answer helpful?

Comment: Thanks everyone, I also found in dplyr a useful function

Answer (score 0):

You can use `fromJSON()` function from the [`jsonlite`](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/jsonlite/vignettes/json-aaquickstart.html) package to parse Python dictionary into R `list` then convert it to a data frame with `as.data.frame()`. After that you can access each variable using `r_df$...`

```r
py_dict <- '{"varname": "value", "varname2": "value2", "varname3": "value3"}'
r_list <- jsonlite::fromJSON(txt = py_dict)
r_df <- as.data.frame(r_list)
r_df

#>   varname varname2 varname3
#> 1   value   value2   value3
```

<sup>Created on 2018-09-16 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>